# Why does Chrome treat this script file as from a different origin?

Tags: google-chrome

I am going through the Augular course at edX. For one of the labs, I launched a file `D:\Documents\Node.js\angularcourse\index.html`. It works fine in Edge. However, in Chrome I get:

> Failed to load file:///D:/Documents/Node.js/angularcourse/app/main.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Isn't main.js on a path that is below the location of the running file?

The source calling main.js in inside zone.js and my `index.html` is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Angular 4.x Application</title>
        <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        </head>
    <body>
        <app>
            Loading...
        </app>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I launched Chrome with `--disable-web-security` then it works ok.

Comment: IIRC chrome considers everything that is not in the same directory to be cross-origin with `file://` protocol. FF behaves as you expected. Anyway, the best if you are interested in web-dev, is to run a local server.

Comment: Does your course material mention anything about a build command like `npm start`, which you should run in order to start a devbelopment web server?

Comment: Thanks to both. My issue was not about setting up a web server. I was just launching from the file system to do some quick tests and met the problem.  Probably @Kaiido is correct and explains it.